# Data source option in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

i'm not getting the data source option in intellij. 
version : 11.0
I wanted to execute few SQL commands.. Is this version of Intellij support Sql ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that [Database Support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/data-sources.html) plug-in is enabled in `Settings` | `Plugins`. This feature is [not available](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) in the Community Edition.